# QAbstracktItemModel correctly remove row only for root element

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a custom QAbstractItemModel

```
class QJsonTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
```

With this removeRows() method

```
    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)

        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        parentItem.removeChildren(position, rows)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Where removeChildren() is from

```
class QJsonTreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self._parent = parent

        self._key = ""
        self._value = ""
        self._type = None
        self._children = list()
        self.itemData = data
    ...

    def getItem(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            item = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item

        return self._rootItem

 
    def removeChildren(self, position, rows):
        if position < 0 or position + rows > len(self._children):
            return False

        for row in range(rows):
            self._children.pop(position)

        return True
```

In my main window class I have right click QMenu() with a couple of methods including delete row method which looks like it:

```
actionDel = rightClickMenu.addAction(self.tr("Delete Item"))
actionDel.triggered.connect(partial(self.treeItemDelete))
...
def treeItemDelete(self):
    index = self.treeView.selectionModel().currentIndex()
    parent = index.parent()
    parentItem = self.model.getItem(parent)
    
    self.model.removeRows(position=index.row(), rows=1, parent=parent)
```

It works correctly for root items, for example if I would like to delete "coa" element he will remove it
[Correclty working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4dhg.png)

But if I would like to delete element "index" it would remove element "asd"
[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyPJb.png)

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: The problem was in getItem() function. It always returns _rootItem. So the correct way is to check in removeRow() like this:
```python
 def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent):
  if(self.data(parent, Qt.EditRole) == None):
   parentItem = self.getItem(parent)
  else:
   parentItem = parent.internalPointer()
                ...
```

Comment: If you found a solution, then post it as an answer, don't use comments. Besides, what you wrote doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. The edit role should have absolutely nothing to do with the parent/child relation, and if the issue is in `getItem()` then you *must fix* `getItem()` not an unrelated function. In fact, the `if` there is just wrong: it should be `if index.isValid():` `item = index.internalPointer()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comment the problem was in `getItem(self, index)` function. Somehow I wrote the wrong `if` statent. @musicamante is right, if the problem is in getItem() function, I need to fix exactly this function, not an unrelated function.

The working code for me is below:

```
    def getItem(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            item = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item

        return self._rootItem
```

And the removeRows() is this:

```
    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)

        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        success = parentItem.removeChildren(position, rows)
        self.endRemoveRows()

        return success
```

Now it removes correctly node and subnodes items.